# Operating on pandas dataframes that may or may not be multiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a few functions that make new columns in a pandas dataframe, as a function of existing columns in the dataframe.  I have two different scenarios that occur here: (1) the dataframe is NOT multiIndex and has a set of columns, say [a,b] and (2) the dataframe is multiIndex and now has the same set of columns headers repeated N times, say [(a,1),(b,1),(a,2),(b,2)....(a,N),(n,N)].

I've been making the aforementioned functions in the style shown below:

```
def f(df):
    if multiindex(df):
        for s df[a].columns:
            df[c,s] = someFunction(df[a,s], df[b,s])
    else:
        df[c] = someFunction(df[a], df[b])
```

Is there another way to do this, without having these if-multi-index/else statement everywhere and duplicating the someFunction code?  I'd prefer NOT to split the multi indexed frame into N smaller dataframes (I often need to filter data or do things and keep the rows consistent across all the 1,2,...N frames, and keeping them together in one frame seems the to be the best way to do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may still have to test if columns is a MultiIndex but this should be cleaner and more efficient.  Caveat, this will not work if your function utilizes summary statistics on the column.  For example, if `someFunction` divides by the the average of column 'a'.

#### Solution

```
def someFunction(a, b):
    return a + b

def f(df):
    df = df.copy()
    ismi = isinstance(df.columns, pd.MultiIndex)
    if ismi:
        df = df.stack()

    df['c'] = someFunction(df['a'], df['a'])

    if ismi:
        df = df.unstack()

    return df
```

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

setup_tuples = []

for c in ['a', 'b']:
        for i in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
            setup_tuples.append((c, i))

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(setup_tuples)

rand_array = np.random.rand(10, len(setup_tuples))

df = pd.DataFrame(rand_array, columns=columns)
```

`df` looks like this

```
          a                             b                    
        one       two     three       one       two     three
0  0.282834  0.490313  0.201300  0.140157  0.467710  0.352555
1  0.838527  0.707131  0.763369  0.265170  0.452397  0.968125
2  0.822786  0.785226  0.434637  0.146397  0.056220  0.003197
3  0.314795  0.414096  0.230474  0.595133  0.060608  0.900934
4  0.334733  0.118689  0.054299  0.237786  0.658538  0.057256
5  0.993753  0.552942  0.665615  0.336948  0.788817  0.320329
6  0.310809  0.199921  0.158675  0.059406  0.801491  0.134779
7  0.971043  0.183953  0.723950  0.909778  0.103679  0.695661
8  0.755384  0.728327  0.029720  0.408389  0.808295  0.677195
9  0.276158  0.978232  0.623972  0.897015  0.253178  0.093772
```

I constructed `df` to have `MultiIndex` columns.  What I'd do is use the `.stack()` method to push the second level of the column index to be the second level of the row index.

`df.stack()` looks like this

```
                a         b
0 one    0.282834  0.140157
  three  0.201300  0.352555
  two    0.490313  0.467710
1 one    0.838527  0.265170
  three  0.763369  0.968125
  two    0.707131  0.452397
2 one    0.822786  0.146397
  three  0.434637  0.003197
  two    0.785226  0.056220
3 one    0.314795  0.595133
  three  0.230474  0.900934
  two    0.414096  0.060608
4 one    0.334733  0.237786
  three  0.054299  0.057256
  two    0.118689  0.658538
5 one    0.993753  0.336948
  three  0.665615  0.320329
  two    0.552942  0.788817
6 one    0.310809  0.059406
  three  0.158675  0.134779
  two    0.199921  0.801491
7 one    0.971043  0.909778
  three  0.723950  0.695661
  two    0.183953  0.103679
8 one    0.755384  0.408389
  three  0.029720  0.677195
  two    0.728327  0.808295
9 one    0.276158  0.897015
  three  0.623972  0.093772
  two    0.978232  0.253178
```

Now you can operate on df.stack() as if the columns were not a `MultiIndex`

#### Demonstration

```
print f(df)
```

will give you what you want

```
          a                             b                             c  \
        one     three       two       one     three       two       one   
0  0.282834  0.201300  0.490313  0.140157  0.352555  0.467710  0.565667   
1  0.838527  0.763369  0.707131  0.265170  0.968125  0.452397  1.677055   
2  0.822786  0.434637  0.785226  0.146397  0.003197  0.056220  1.645572   
3  0.314795  0.230474  0.414096  0.595133  0.900934  0.060608  0.629591   
4  0.334733  0.054299  0.118689  0.237786  0.057256  0.658538  0.669465   
5  0.993753  0.665615  0.552942  0.336948  0.320329  0.788817  1.987507   
6  0.310809  0.158675  0.199921  0.059406  0.134779  0.801491  0.621618   
7  0.971043  0.723950  0.183953  0.909778  0.695661  0.103679  1.942086   
8  0.755384  0.029720  0.728327  0.408389  0.677195  0.808295  1.510767   
9  0.276158  0.623972  0.978232  0.897015  0.093772  0.253178  0.552317   


      three       two  
0  0.402600  0.980626  
1  1.526739  1.414262  
2  0.869273  1.570453  
3  0.460948  0.828193  
4  0.108599  0.237377  
5  1.331230  1.105884  
6  0.317349  0.399843  
7  1.447900  0.367907  
8  0.059439  1.456654  
9  1.247944  1.956464
```

Comment: Thanks, the stack method is very helpful here.  Question: is this OK if the dataframe is large and a bunch of these methods are called repeatedly?  E.g. are stack and unstack actually allocating new dataframes and populating all the new memory each time, or just changing the view on the same values in memory?